# dlib "Filter windows must be small enough to fit into the padded image"

Tags: c++, dlib

I'm getting the following error when attempting to process an image with `dlib`. I'm using the `facial-recognition` npm package, but this is just a wrapper around `dlib`.

```
**************************** FATAL ERROR DETECTED ****************************

Error detected at line 1971. 
Error detected in file /Users/botvinick/Desktop/GitHub/api.benbotvinick.com/node_modules/dlib-build/dlib/dlib/dlib/dnn/cpu_dlib.cpp. 
Error detected in function void dlib::cpu::tensor_conv::operator()(const bool, dlib::tensor &, const dlib::tensor &, const dlib::tensor &).

Failing expression was filters.nr() <= data.nr() + 2*last_padding_y. 
Filter windows must be small enough to fit into the padded image.

******************************************************************************

libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly returned
```

I have tried different types and sizes of images, to no avail.

**Edit:** It may be important to mention that I am getting the image from a URL and converting it into a `CvImage`. Perhaps somewhere in this conversion process, the image is being truncated, but the question remains, how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

convert the image size to a square one e.g. 100x200 --> 100x100 or 200x200. You need to use your judgement based on the actual image whether to scale up/down or truncate in one direction (x or y). Since scaling may distort appropriate padding to make it a square image may help.